# XAMPP MySQL shut down unexpectedly

Tags: mysql

Confused as to why my XAMPP is no longer working. I've been using it for the past month and it's been working as expected and as of today when I set it up and tryed to run MySQL, an error is preventing it from running properly. My Apache is running fine but not MySQL.

This is within the MySQL error log:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-05-02 18:24:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-05-02 18:24:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-05-02 18:24:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-05-02 18:24:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-05-02 18:24:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-05-02 18:24:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-05-02 18:24:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-05-02 18:24:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-05-02 18:24:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-05-02 18:24:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '\uniyear3\NathanBayne_wst1\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full;     Please wait ...
2020-05-02 18:24:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '\uniyear3\NathanBayne_wst1\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size     is now 12 MB.
2020-05-02 18:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-05-02 18:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 356547; transaction id 344
2020-05-02 18:24:03 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-05-02 18:24:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from     G:\uniyear3\NathanBayne_wst1\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-05-02 18:24:03 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

This is my Apache error log:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: \\uniyear3\\NathanBayne_wst1\\xampp\\php\\ext\\pdo_sqlite (The specified module could not be found.), \\uniyear3\\NathanBayne_wst1\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_pdo_sqlite.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[Sat May 02 18:23:54.452382 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2312:tid 640] AH00455: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat May 02 18:23:54.452382 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2312:tid 640] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Aug 11 2019 12:20:04
[Sat May 02 18:23:54.452382 2020] [core:notice] [pid 2312:tid 640] AH00094: Command line: 'g:\\uniyear3\\nathanbayne_wst1\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d G:/uniyear3/NathanBayne_wst1/xampp/apache'
[Sat May 02 18:23:54.455341 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2312:tid 640] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2192
[Sat May 02 18:23:54.653167 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 2192:tid 648] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat May 02 18:23:54.693962 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 2192:tid 648] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: \\uniyear3\\NathanBayne_wst1\\xampp\\php\\ext\\pdo_sqlite (The specified module could not be found.), \\uniyear3\\NathanBayne_wst1\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_pdo_sqlite.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[Sat May 02 18:23:54.712700 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2192:tid 648] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

8:24:06 [mysql] Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. 18:24:06 [mysql] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
18:24:06 [mysql] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. 18:24:06 [mysql] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check 18:24:06 [mysql] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues 
18:24:06 [mysql] If you need more help, copy and post this 18:24:06 [mysql] entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: There is no mysql error anywhere.

Comment: Is there anything within the error logs that indicate what the issue is with why MySQL won't start? It also displays this to me:

Comment: 18:24:06  [mysql]  Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
18:24:06  [mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
18:24:06  [mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
18:24:06  [mysql]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
18:24:06  [mysql]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
18:24:06  [mysql]  If you need more help, copy and post this
18:24:06  [mysql]  entire log window on the forums

Comment: may be the port is in use

Comment: It's definitely not in use elsewhere. Checked for that just in case that was the issue.